Cannot authenticate in a .NET 8 maui blazor hybrid app for Microsoft Entra id
I have an existing Blazor server app that connects to Microsoft Entra id and an Azure SQL database just fine. The client wanted to create a mobile app for patients. The blazor server app is just for the client's admin.
I have tried creating a .NET 8 MAUI Blazor Hybrid app (I use Jetbrains Rider since it is the only way I could get the Android and iOS emulators to run on my mac). I have followed just about every tutorial I could find, with no luck. I have even asked ChatGPT, which gave me a lot of useful information, but still couldn't figure out how to do it.
Only one solution opened the Microsoft login screen and let me enter my password and authentication code, but it didn't authenticate. I don't get any errors either. The link to that project is below.
https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main/Auth
I have tried so many different solutions, but I am at a loss here. I only have about 3 more months to build this mobile app too (Android and iOS).
Can anyone help? I can give the code that I have, but it is so many different "solutions", so I won't list any code here because of that.

I should also mention that the issues I was having had a lot to do with things like "WithParentActivityOrWindow", not being able to get the current activity, referencing an android app inside a shared blazor app that targeted ios after creating one solution with a shared blazor project, android, and ios project, etc...

Also, authenticating to ms entra id with msal will allow that client's admin to use there current login, but I will also need to figure out how to add another login method for the patients, which is another issue for me to solve.
